# Program entries does´t publish until control panel action

Tags: entries

I have schedule entries but they doesn´t publish at the time defined, to publish they need the time and and action on control panel like save a template, etc.

I guess pseudo cronjob is not working.

Ani help?

Comment: Are your time zone settings correct? Probably they will appear one or more hours too late because of wrong settings.

Comment: Doble checked...I did echo date("F j, Y, g:i a") to verify. 

I guess is something related to pseudo cron, because it suppose to check time and compare to publish time in every visit

Comment: The problem wash that the template has activated cache. Thanks.